# how to create xml template c# with different(dynamic) node name

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create several xml node with same child nodes but the name of each node should be differenti.e

```
<Rootnode>
<somename1>
<testFilename><![CDATA[some-name]]></testFilename>
<parentDirectory><![CDATA[some-path]]></parentDirectory>
</somename1>

<somename2>
<testFilename><![CDATA[some-diff-name]]></testFilename>
<parentDirectory><![CDATA[some-diff-path]]></parentDirectory>
</somename2>

<somename3>
<testFilename><![CDATA[some-diff-name]]></testFilename>
<parentDirectory><![CDATA[some-diff-path]]></parentDirectory>
</somename3>

</Rootnode>
```

that "somename " will be obtained as string from another function

need to create the template of this node as number of nodes will 100's 
by using seralization i m doing it like this

```
public class template1 
{        
    public template1()
    {            
    }
    private String Filename;
    private String Parentpath;
    public System.Xml.XmlCDataSection testFilename
    {
        get
        {
            return new System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Filename);
        }
        set
        {
            this.Filename = value.Value;

        }
    }
    public System.Xml.XmlCDataSection parentDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            return new System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Parentpath);
        }
        set
        {
            this.Parentpath = value.Value;
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//will vary as per the no. of nodes to be generated
        {
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlCDataSection FCData, PCData;
            String fname, pname;
            fname = "some file name";
            FCData = xdoc.CreateCDataSection(fname);
            template1 a = new template1();
            a.testFilename = FCData;
            pname = "some path";
            PCData = xdoc.CreateCDataSection(fname);
            a.parentDirectory = PCData;

            Serialize(a);
        }

    }
    static public void Serialize(template1 t)
     {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(template1));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\abc\\xelname.xml",true))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, t);
        }

    }
}
```

this the output file which is generated need different name instead of that template1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<template1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<testFilename><![CDATA[some file name0]]></testFilename>
<parentDirectory><![CDATA[some file name0]]></parentDirectory>
</template1>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<template1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<testFilename><![CDATA[some file name1]]></testFilename>
<parentDirectory><![CDATA[some file name1]]></parentDirectory>
</template1>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<template1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<testFilename><![CDATA[some file name2]]></testFilename>
<parentDirectory><![CDATA[some file name2]]></parentDirectory>
</template1>
```

and also how can I ignore that attributes of template1 node

Comment: As a very basic starting point, consider a method that takes in your required node name, and returns a node with it's properties set and children attached.

Comment: Need to create the template so i can just fill the values dynamically into the node..format of node is not going to change just the values will diifer.

Comment: I may have originally misunderstood what you're asking for - are you asking how to create an xml template that is "mail merged" with your data and then appended to existing nodes in another xml document?

Comment: yes..like that just the name of node will differ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a seperate XML file for your template, with some sort of special codes where you want to insert your data. For example:

```
<example value="[MyData]" />
```

Create a method which takes in the required node name, and loads this XML file and loops through it, checking for codes in every value, attribute etc. and replacing them with your data. Either add these nodes to a new root node with the provided name, or rename the root node to your provided name.

Then simply return that node tree, ready to append wherever you may need it. This allows you to have multiple templates which all contain the same custom "fields" to be replaced out.